# request not reaching the server

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat7, requestfactory

I am having problem with requests that stays on pending status on the browser.
I am using GWT with requestfactory and Apache tomcat.
I tried to see the tomcat access log but it seems that requesfactory's requests (which stays on pending) are not reaching the server.
Any suggestion?

Comment: What do your browser's dev tools say?

Comment: when i open dev tools on chrome i can see that the gwtRequest's requests still on pending status (waiting server's response) and nothing happen.